# Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js"

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, expo, babeljs

I am making an app in react native expo. It runs on web browser but fails to run on android simulator or expo go app on my phone. i get 2 errors :-

Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

any help would be appreciated

my expo sdk : 44,

my package.json

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "ngrok": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

my babel.config

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the `reanimated` [doc](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/),

- Install `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next`
- Edit babel plugin config

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

- Clear Metro Bundler cache & start expo `expo start --clear`

That should solve the issue!

Comment: This was the solution . Thanks alot man!

Comment: This works for me, thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same error before, and I did 2 things:

1. Actually installed react-native-reanimated by typing
   `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next` in cmd.
2. Made sure everything in my expo was up to date by typing
   `expo update` and pressing `y` to get every module on the compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the server
2. run **expo r -c** to clear the cache.